# Sign Git tag with Maven release plugin?

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

Is there a way to get the Maven release plugin to sign the Git tag it creates during a `mvn release:prepare` execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this seemed to be currently not available.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-486

But this does not mean it might not be possible somehow?

Comment: Right. There's a comment about enabling with a `-Dmaven.scm.gitexe.sign_tags` flag and a 'diff' to make that option work, but doesn't seem to be in my Maven version (3.0.3/2011-02-28).  I don't know how to check if it was accepted for 3.0.4 (short of downloading 3.0.4 to try it out.).

Comment: It will not be in Maven itself it's only in the maven-scm-git-provider which is fixed based on the issue tracker (not marked as fixed and not scheduled for a particular release). May be you can vote for it.

Comment: Got it (still getting used to Maven being so heavily plugin-based).  I will vote for it.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this issue is still open (5 years later) but has now moved to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-486

Comment: @Kevinoid current git version supports tag.forceSignAnnotated config option, which will force git to sign tags as maven uses annotated tags when releasing

Comment: this bug has been resolved  please provide some feedback if possible (it is very easy to test)

Answer (score 4):

Staring from version 2.9.0 git supports **tag.forceSignAnnotated** config option, which will force git to sign tags as maven uses annotated tags when releasing. Just put

```
[tag]
    forceSignAnnotated = true
```

into your **.gitconfig** file.

Answer (score 0):

That has been added in maven-scm 1.11.1

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-486

https://github.com/apache/maven-scm/commit/6c31363a807973b96a178c41dcc1c2c7d781e3bf